# How to get text between two strings in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing

I have a text file that contains this text:

```
What's New in this Version
==========================
-This is the text I want to get 
-It can have 1 or many lines
-These equal signs are repeated throughout the file to separate sections

Primary Category
================
```

I just want to get everything between ========================== and Primary Category and store that block of text in a variable. I thought the following match method would work but it gives me, NoMethodError: undefined method `match'

```
    f = File.open(metadataPath, "r")
    line = f.readlines
    whatsNew = f.match(/==========================(.*)Primary Category/m).strip
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If ruby regexps behave like perl, then you want to use the //s and not the //m modifier, which makes . include \n as well. //m (at least in perl) is something different that modifies how ^ and $ match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f` is a file descriptor - you want to match on the text in the file, which you read into `line`. What I prefer to do instead of reading the text into an array (which is hard to regex on) is to just read it into one string:

```
contents = File.open(metadataPath) { |f| f.read }
contents.match(/==========================(.*)Primary Category/m)[1].strip
```

The last line produces your desired output:

```
-This is the text I want to get \n-It can have 1 or many lines\n-These equal signs are repeated throughout the file to separate sections"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = File.open(metadataPath, "r")
line = f.readlines
line =~ /==========================(.*)Primary Category/m
whatsNew = $1
```

you may want to consider refining the .* though as that could be greedy

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that *readlines* gives you an array of strings (one for each line), but the regular expression you're using needs a single string.  You could read the file as one string:

```
contents = File.read(metadataPath)
puts contents[/^=+(.*?)Primary Category/m]
# => ==========================
# => -This is the text I want to get
# => -It can have 1 or many lines
# => -These equal signs are repeated throughout the file to separate sections
# =>
# => Primary Category
```

or you could join the  lines into a single string before applying the regular expression:

```
lines = File.readlines(metadataPath)
puts lines.join[/^=+(.*?)Primary Category/m]
# => ==========================
# => -This is the text I want to get
# => -It can have 1 or many lines
# => -These equal signs are repeated throughout the file to separate sections
# =>
# => Primary Category
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd take is read in the lines, find out which line numbers are a series of equal signs (using `Array#find_index`), and group the lines into chunks from the line after the equal signs to the line before (or two lines before) the next lot of equal signs (probably using `Enumerable#each_cons(2)` and `map`). That way I don't have to modify much if the section headings change.